# 次もうかかんでもわかるだろ - What does かかんでも mean here?

Tags: meaning, nuances

In the little busters VN, one of the heroines 鈴 created a cleaning schedule for the male dorm toilets. But in the schedule, only the guys in her friend group are included, in a repeating manner. This is expressed the following way:

> 『そうじスケジュール』
> 『５月１７日（木）：直枝理樹』
> 『５月２４日（木）：井ノ原まさと』
> 『５月さいご：けんご』
> 『６月はじめ：きょーすけ』
> 『次：りき』
> 『その次：まさと』
> 『次：けんご』
> 『次あいつ』
> 『次もうかかんでもわかるだろ』

As you can see, the names keep getting repeated, until the protag says the last line, which I could kinda understand what he meant by it, but what is かかん here? Or is this perhaps some kind of pattern, かかんでもわかる?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 書かんでも, Kansai-ben for 書かなくても.